# How to apply this ajax preloader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#loading')
        .hide()
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
});
```

Loading....

Can someone tell me where to apply this to an actual ajax call by an example? I'm just confused on the application of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `ajaxStart` on `document`

> [**From Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)
>
> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $loading = $('#loading').hide();
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
       $loading.show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $loading.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I put this before the ajax call or after? I want to know how to apply it to an actual ajax example.

Comment: Anywhere...these are global ajax handlers and will fire for any `$.ajax` request made. So you set them up once ...then if you have 10 different ajax calls in your code...they are triggered for any of them